# Libsvm: tools/easy.py

Tags: python, svm, libsvm

The script tools/easy.py uses only rbf kernel. How can I change this script to perform the experiments with another kernels, in particular linear kernel ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `svm-train [options] training_set_file [model_file]` the option for which svm_type you wnat.
From the README file in the source code:

```
options:
-s svm_type : set type of SVM (default 0)
    0 -- C-SVC
    1 -- nu-SVC
    2 -- one-class SVM
    3 -- epsilon-SVR
    4 -- nu-SVR
-t kernel_type : set type of kernel function (default 2)
    0 -- linear: u'*v
    1 -- polynomial: (gamma*u'*v + coef0)^degree
    2 -- radial basis function: exp(-gamma*|u-v|^2)
    3 -- sigmoid: tanh(gamma*u'*v + coef0)
    4 -- precomputed kernel (kernel values in training_set_file)
```

Thus linear would be `-t 0`

There are other options listed in the README as well which change the parameters used in each kernel function.